# Download from Firebase as JSON using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to export a Firebase object from JavaScript as JSON and download it. For example, [this item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imGUs.png) that is in the `patients/` reference. I would like to download it on a .json file with this format:

```
"-LCZPCkiGCNhFaQ8ckJ-" : {
  "altura" : 165,
  "apellido" : "Salas",
  "extra" : {
    "Jubilado" : "No",
    "Localidad" : "Madrid",
    "Telefono" : "698532147"
  },
  "fechaNacimiento" : "14/10/1961",
  "nombre" : "Paquita",
  "sexo" : "Mujer"
}
```

I have only been able to download a file stored in Storage but not in Realtime Database

```
 firebase.storage().ref('grabaciones/').child(grabacion).getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
  let a = document.createElement("a");
  a.download = grabacion;
  a.href = url;
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
}).catch(function (error) {
  // Handle any errors
  console.log(error);
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Updated code, where the element is obtained as a JSON and is downloaded as a .json. Only works in Firefox:

```
$scope.exportarJSON = function (paciente) {
        console.log(grabacion);
        firebase.database().ref('pacientes/').child(pacinte).once('value', function (paciente) {
          download(paciente + ".json", JSON.stringify(paciente.val()));
        });
    };



 function download(filename, text) {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/json;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);

    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have managed to do this by obtaining the data from Firebase, and applying JSON.stringify () to that data. Later to download them as a .json file, I created a Blob with the string following the code of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26158579/6304714). Thanks for the answers, they have been inspiring

```
 $scope.exportarJSON = function (paciente) {
        console.log(grabacion);
        firebase.database().ref('pacientes/').child(pacinte).once('value', function (paciente) {
          download(paciente + ".json", paciente.val());
        });
    };


function download(filename, paciente) {
    let file = JSON.stringify(paciente);
    let blob = new Blob([file], {type: "application/json"});
    let url  = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    let element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', url);
    element.setAttribute('download', paciente.nombre + ".json");

    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

Ever piece of data in your Firebase Database has its own unique URL. For example, I quickly imported your sample data into one of my databases, and it now lives on `https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/50408054/-LCZPCkiGCNhFaQ8ckJ-`.

If you go to that URL, you will be prompted to log in. Since you don't have access to my project, you can't see my database console.

But you **can** access the data as JSON. Since I've granted public read access to the data, you can access it as JSON through this URL: `https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/50408054/-LCZPCkiGCNhFaQ8ckJ-.json`. As you can see, that is the same URL as before, but now with `.json` added at the end.

This is part of Firebase's REST API, which is fully documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start. You should be able to use this REST URL in your download link, as long as the data is publicly readable.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I need the information not accessible publicly. I have managed to do it following @RenaudTarnec 's strategy, as you can see in the answer, but thanks for the interesting information.

Comment: I believe the link changed to: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Callable Function, as follows:

**Cloud Function code (index.js)**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.getJSON = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

    return admin.database().ref('yourLocation').once('value')
        .then(function(snapshot) {
            return snapshot.val();
    });

    //Note that yourLocation is hardcoded in this example but could be obtained from 
    //the data parameter, which value comes from the JavaScript call in your web page    

});
```

**Code in a web page, for example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.3/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.3/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.3/firebase-functions.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script>

    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
        apiKey: "....",
        authDomain: "",
        databaseURL: "",
        projectId: ""
    };

    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    var getJSON = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getJSON');
    getJSON().then(function(result) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result.data));
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Getting the Error details.
        var code = error.code;
        var message = error.message;
        var details = error.details;
        // ...
    });

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

You will find the doc on Callable Functions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Note that you can call this Function from and iOS or Android app as well.

You could do something similar with a simple HTTPS Cloud Function and call it as a REST API endpoint (for example with the Axios library). One of the advantage of using a Callable Function is that "Firebase Authentication and FCM tokens are automatically included in requests" so you can easily restrict the calls to authorized users only.

Comment: Ok, I think I understood the idea. I tried to implement it without resorting to Firebase functions and it seems to work, I have added it to the question
I have also added the download function to download the file as a .json, as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18197341/6304714), but I only get it to work in Firefox. The part of the download would be the one missing in your code. Thanks for your answer